# ftp file upload problems in php

Tags: php, ftp

I have been googling the whole day trying everything I can find, but nothing works. I'm starting to get desperate.

I'm trying to make a script that can upload a file to my ftp account, but so far I've not been able to get it working.

I'm getting these errors:

> Warning: ftp_put(): Opening data channel for file transfer. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AA\dwsite\ftptest\up.php on line 49
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AA\dwsite\ftptest\up.php on line 49

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
if (isset ( $_FILES ['be_file'] )) {

    $file_size = $_FILES ['be_file'] ['be_file'];
    $file_type = $_FILES ['be_file'] ['type'];
    $source_file = $_FILES ['be_file'] ['tmp_name'];
    $destination_file = $_FILES ['be_file'] ['name'];
//ftp details   
    $ftp_server = 'ip of ftp';
    $ftp_port = 'port number';
    $ftp_user_name = 'username';
    $ftp_user_pass = 'pass';

    // set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect ( $ftp_server, $ftp_port );
    ftp_pasv ( $conn_id, true );
    // login with username and password

    $login_result = ftp_login ( $conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

    // upload a file
    if (ftp_put ( $conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY )) {
        echo "successfully uploaded $source_file\n";
        exit ();
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem while uploading $source_file\n";
        exit ();
    }
    // close the connection
    ftp_close ( $conn_id );
    echo "Success";
}

?>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" /> <input type="submit" />

        <ul>
            <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['be_file']['name'];  ?>

            <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['be_file']['size'];  ?>

            <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['be_file']['type']?>

        </ul>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**max_execution_time integer**

- Add `max_execution_time = 300` into your php.ini file server. Then restart your php-fpm service and restart your server.
- Or add `set_time_limit(0);` in your code.
- Or If you havn't access to your php.ini file, you could extend the maximum execution time like this: 
  `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`

This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.

The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc. Please see the set_time_limit() function for more details.

You can not change this setting with ini_set() when running in safe mode. The only workaround is to turn off safe mode or by changing the time limit in the php.ini.

[Php doc -> Max_execution_time](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Comment: Or add `set_time_limit(0);` in your code. Maybe you can update answer @Pierre with that.

Comment: So i added the set_time_limit(0); to my code and the execution time error is gone, but i still get the "Warning: ftp_put(): Opening data channel for file transfer. in C:\xampp\htdocs\AA\dwsite\ftptest\up.php on line 49" im trying to upload a jpg picture of 150kb size. should it really take that long? and just like prviously, nothing is uploaded to ftp account.

Comment: Have you test in your php.ini and restart your php-fpm service and server ?

Comment: yes, i have restarted my localhost  Apache and MySQL too, but changing php.ini is not an option as i will have to deploy this code on a paid host server to whom i have no access over php.ini. 

At this point i don't even know what to look for more. I have spent whole weekend trying to make this one particular feature work, read countless posts right here on stackoverflow and other sites, tried all the things, yet it is not functional.

Comment: Ok, If it is not, you could extend the maximum execution time like this:
`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`

Comment: @pierre  when i add  "ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);" nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had this error because you called the `ftp_pasv` function before the login:

```
ftp_pasv ( $conn_id, true );
$login_result = ftp_login ( $conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );
```

Should be:

```
$login_result = ftp_login ( $conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );
ftp_pasv ( $conn_id, true );
```

If it can help someone. ;)